# I am getting BeanFactory error: NoSuchBeanDefinitionException and I can't figure out how to solve it

Tags: java, spring

I was given the task to work on an existing AngularJS SPA (app B). This app uses code from another app (app B) to get information from the database.  Both; app A and app B use the same database.  the goal is to modify app B to get customers, Locations and Docks from a different database.  My goal it to still use some of the same code that app A uses and to create new code for app B and then access the new database to get the information.

When I try to start the app (Eclipse Oxigen) I get an exception thrown by the BeanFactory.

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'contextServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field **'customersRepo'**; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type **'com.csoln.lv.data.cld.dao.CustomersRepo'** available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

I suspect that the bean isn’t defined in the Spring Context but I don't know how to define it.  I have tried the suggestions found on other posts and nothing works.  I will post the code and relevant files next...

Keep in mind that I am pretty new on Spring, REstful Services, etc.  I hope you can help me solving this error.  Thank you in advance.

SERVICE FILE

```
package com.csoln.lv.service;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import com.csoln.lv.cld.bo.CustomerBo;
import com.csoln.lv.cld.bo.DockBo;
import com.csoln.lv.cld.bo.LocationBo;

public interface ContextService {

    public List<CustomerBo> getCustomersFiltered(); 
    public Map<String, CustomerBo> getCustomerMapFiltered();
    public CustomerBo getCustomer(Integer id);
    public List<CustomerBo> getAllCustomers();
    public List<CustomerBo> getCustomers();
    public Map<String, CustomerBo> getCustomerMap();    
    public Map<Integer, CustomerBo> getCustomerMapById();

    public List<LocationBo> getLocationsFiltered(CustomerBo customer);  
    public Map<String, LocationBo> getLocationMapFiltered(CustomerBo customer);
    public Map<Integer, LocationBo> getLocationMapByIdFiltered(CustomerBo customer);
    public LocationBo getLocation(Integer customerId, Integer id);
    public List<LocationBo> getAllLocations(CustomerBo customer);
    public List<LocationBo> getLocations(CustomerBo customer);

    public List<DockBo> getDocksFiltered(LocationBo location);  
    public Map<String, DockBo> getDockMapFiltered(LocationBo location); 
    public Map<Integer, DockBo> getDockMapByIdFiltered(LocationBo location);
    public DockBo getDock(Integer customerId, Integer locationId, Integer id);
    public List<DockBo> getAllDocks(LocationBo location);
    public List<DockBo> getDocks(LocationBo location);

    public List<DockBo> getSubDocks(DockBo dock);
    public Map<String, DockBo> getSubDockMap(DockBo dock);
    public Map<Integer, DockBo> getSubDockMapById(DockBo dock);
}
```

---

SERVICE IMPL

```
package com.csoln.lv.service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.SortedMap;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Example;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort.Direction;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

// For Liveview
import com.csoln.lv.cld.bo.CustomerBo;
import com.csoln.lv.cld.bo.DockBo;
import com.csoln.lv.cld.bo.LocationBo;
import com.csoln.lv.data.cld.dao.CustomersRepo;
import com.csoln.lv.data.cld.dao.DocksRepo;
import com.csoln.lv.data.cld.dao.LocationsRepo;
import com.csoln.lv.data.dom.Customers;
import com.csoln.lv.data.dom.Docks;
import com.csoln.lv.data.dom.Locations;
import com.csoln.lv.data.id.DockId;
import com.csoln.lv.data.id.LocationId;

@Service
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public class ContextServiceImpl implements ContextService {

    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ContextServiceImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    private CustomersRepo customersRepo;
    @Autowired
    private LocationsRepo locationsRepo;
    @Autowired
    private DocksRepo docksRepo;

    private String customerPrefix = "C_";
    private String locationPrefix = "L_";
    private String dockPrefix = "D_";

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.csoln.service.data.ContextService#getCustomers()
     */
    @Override
    public List<CustomerBo> getCustomersFiltered() {
        List<String> filter = this.getGrantedAuthorities(this.customerPrefix);
        List<CustomerBo> customers = new ArrayList<>();
        List<CustomerBo> clients = this.getCustomers(true);
        if( clients != null && filter != null && clients.size() > 0 && filter.size() > 0 ) {
            Stream<CustomerBo> stream = clients.stream().filter( entry -> filter.contains(entry.getId().toString()));
            customers = stream.collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
        if( log.isDebugEnabled() ) {            
            log.debug(clients);
        }
        return customers;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.csoln.service.data.ContextService#getCustomerMap()
     */
    @Override
    public Map<String, CustomerBo> getCustomerMapFiltered() {
        List<CustomerBo> customers = this.getCustomersFiltered();
        Map<String, CustomerBo> clients = new HashMap<>();
        if( customers != null && customers.size() > 0 ) {
            customers.forEach(c -> clients.put(c.getAbbreviation(), c));
        }
        if( log.isDebugEnabled() ) {            
            log.debug(clients);
        }
        return clients;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.csoln.service.ContextService#getCustomer(java.lang.Integer)
     */
    @Override
    public CustomerBo getCustomer(Integer id) {
        return new CustomerBo().toBo(this.customersRepo.findOne(id));
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.csoln.service.ContextService#getCustomers()
     */
    @Override
    public List<CustomerBo> getAllCustomers() {
        List<CustomerBo> customers = this.getCustomers(false);
        return customers;
    }

    @Override
    public List<CustomerBo> getCustomers() {
        List<CustomerBo> customers = this.getCustomers(true);
        return customers;
    }

    private List<CustomerBo> getCustomers(Boolean active) {
        Example<Customers> example = null;
        List<Customers> entities = null;
        if( active ) {
            Customers probe = new Customers();
            probe.setActiveEntry(active);
            example = Example.of(probe);
            entities = this.customersRepo.findAll(example, new Sort(Direction.ASC, "shortName"));
        } else {
            entities = this.customersRepo.findAll(new Sort(Direction.ASC, "shortName"));
        }

        List<CustomerBo> customers = new ArrayList<>();
        if( entities != null && entities.size() > 0 ) {
            entities.forEach(c -> {
                customers.add(new CustomerBo().toBo(c));
            });
        }
        return customers;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.csoln.service.data.ContextService#getCustomerMapById()
     */
    public Map<Integer, CustomerBo> getCustomerMapById() {
        SortedMap<Integer, CustomerBo> clients = new TreeMap<>();
        List<CustomerBo> customers = this.getAllCustomers();
        if( customers != null && !customers.isEmpty() ) {
            customers.forEach(c -> clients.put(c.getId(), c) );
        }
        if( log.isDebugEnabled() ) {            
            log.debug(clients);
        }
        return clients;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.csoln.service.data.ContextService#getCustomerMapByAbbreviation()
     */
    @Override
    public Map<String, CustomerBo> getCustomerMap() {
        SortedMap<String, CustomerBo> clients = new TreeMap<>();
        List<CustomerBo> customers = this.getAllCustomers();
        if( customers != null && !customers.isEmpty() ) {
            customers.forEach(c -> clients.put(c.getAbbreviation(), c));
        }
        if( log.isDebugEnabled() ) {            
            log.debug(clients);
        }
        return clients;
    }



    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.csoln.service.data.ContextService#getLocations(com.csoln.web.bean.CustomerBean)
     */
    @Override
    public List<LocationBo> getLocationsFiltered(CustomerBo customer) {
        List<String> filter = this.getGrantedAuthorities(this.locationPrefix + customer.getId() + "_");     
        List<LocationBo> locations = new ArrayList<>();
        List<LocationBo> ls = this.getLocations(customer);
        if( ls != null && !ls.isEmpty() ) {
            locations = ls.stream().filter( l-> filter.contains(l.getId().toString())).collect(Collectors.toList());
            Collections.sort(locations, (l1, l2) -> (l1.getId() < l2.getId())?1:0);
        }
        if( log.isDebugEnabled() ) {

        }
        return locations;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.csoln.service.data.ContextService#getLocationMap(com.csoln.web.bean.CustomerBean)
     */
    @Override
    public Map<String, LocationBo> getLocationMapFiltered(CustomerBo customer) {
        Map<String, LocationBo> locations = new TreeMap<>();
        List<LocationBo> locs = this.getLocationsFiltered(customer);
        if( locs != null && !locs.isEmpty() ) {
            locs.forEach(l -> locations.put(l.getAbbreviation(), l));           
        }
        log.debug(locations);
        return locations;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.csoln.service.data.ContextService#getLocationMapById(com.csoln.web.bean.CustomerBean, java.lang.String)
     */
    @Override
    public Map<Integer, LocationBo> getLocationMapByIdFiltered(CustomerBo customer) {
        Map<Integer, LocationBo> locations = new TreeMap<>();
        List<LocationBo> locs = this.getLocationsFiltered(customer);
        if( locs != null && !locs.isEmpty() ) {
            locs.forEach(l -> locations.put(l.getId(), l));         
        }
        log.debug(locations);
        return locations;
    }   

    @Override
    public LocationBo getLocation(Integer customerId, Integer id) {
        LocationId locId = new LocationId(customerId, id);
        return new LocationBo().toBo(this.locationsRepo.findOne(locId));
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.csoln.service.ContextService#getLocations(com.csoln.common.bo.CustomerBo)
     */
    @Override
//  @Cacheable(cacheNames = "context", key="#root.target+#root.methodName+#customer")
    public List<LocationBo> getAllLocations(CustomerBo customer) {
        List<LocationBo> locations = this.getLocations(customer, false);
        return locations;
    }

    @Override
    public List<LocationBo> getLocations(CustomerBo customer) {
        List<LocationBo> locations = this.getLocations(customer, true);
        return locations;
    }

    private List<LocationBo> getLocations(CustomerBo customer, Boolean active) {
        Locations probe = new Locations(customer.getId());
        if( active ) {
            probe.setActiveEntry(active);
        }
        List<Locations> entities = this.locationsRepo.findAll(Example.of(probe), new Sort(Direction.ASC, "shortName"));
        List<LocationBo> locations = new ArrayList<>();
        if( entities != null && entities.size() > 0 ) {
            entities.forEach( l->{
                locations.add(new LocationBo().toBo(l));
            });
        }
        return locations;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.csoln.service.data.ContextService#getDocks(com.csoln.web.bean.LocationBean)
     */
    @Override
    public List<DockBo> getDocksFiltered(LocationBo location) {
        List<String> filter = this.getGrantedAuthorities(this.dockPrefix + location.getCustomerId() + "_" + location.getId() + "_");

        List<DockBo> docs = this.getDocks(location);

        List<DockBo> docks = new ArrayList<>();
        if( docs != null && filter != null && !docs.isEmpty() ) {           
            docks = docs.stream().filter( d-> filter.contains(d.getId().toString())).collect(Collectors.toList());
            Collections.sort(docks, (d1, d2) -> (d1.getId() < d2.getId())?1:0);
        }

        if( log.isDebugEnabled() ) {
            log.debug(docks);
        }
        return docks;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.csoln.service.data.ContextService#getDockMap(com.csoln.web.bean.LocationBean)
     */
    @Override
    public Map<String, DockBo> getDockMapFiltered(LocationBo location) {        
        Map<String, DockBo> docks = new TreeMap<>();
        List<DockBo> dcks = this.getDocksFiltered(location);        
        if( dcks != null & !dcks.isEmpty() ) {
            dcks.forEach(d -> docks.put(d.getAbbreviation(), d));
        }       
        if( log.isDebugEnabled() ) {
            log.debug(docks);
        }
        return docks;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.csoln.service.data.ContextService#getDockMapById(com.csoln.web.bean.LocationBean, java.lang.String)
     */
    @Override
    public Map<Integer, DockBo> getDockMapByIdFiltered(LocationBo location) {
        Map<Integer, DockBo> docks = new TreeMap<>();
        List<DockBo> dcks = this.getDocksFiltered(location);        
        if( dcks != null & !dcks.isEmpty() ) {
            dcks.forEach(d -> docks.put(d.getId(), d));
        }       
        if( log.isDebugEnabled() ) {
            log.debug(docks);
        }
        return docks;
    }

    @Override
    public DockBo getDock(Integer customerId, Integer locationId, Integer id) {
        DockId dockId = new DockId(customerId, locationId, id);
        return new DockBo().toBo(this.docksRepo.findOne(dockId));
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.csoln.service.ContextService#getDocks(com.csoln.common.bo.LocationBo)
     */
    @Override
//  @Cacheable(cacheNames = "context", key="#root.target+#root.methodName+#location")
    public List<DockBo> getAllDocks(LocationBo location) {
        List<DockBo> docks = this.getDocksIfActive(location.getCustomerId(), location.getId(), false);
        return docks;
    }

    @Override
    public List<DockBo> getDocks(LocationBo location) {
        List<DockBo> docks = this.getDocksIfActive(location.getCustomerId(), location.getId(), true);
        return docks;
    }

    private List<DockBo> getDocksIfActive(Integer customerId, Integer locationId, Boolean active) {
        List<DockBo> docks = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Docks> entities = null;
        Docks probe = new Docks(customerId, locationId);
        if( active ) {
            probe.setActiveEntry(active);
        } 
        entities = this.docksRepo.findAll(Example.of(probe), new Sort(Direction.ASC, "shortName"));
        List<DockBo> subdocks = new ArrayList<>();
        if( entities != null && entities.size() > 0 ) {
            entities.forEach( d-> {
                subdocks.addAll(getSubDocks(new DockBo().toBo(d)));
                docks.add(new DockBo().toBo(d));            
            });
        }
        subdocks.forEach(sd -> {
            docks.remove(sd);
        });     
        return docks;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)    
     * @see com.csoln.service.data.ContextService#getSubDocks(com.csoln.web.bean.DockBean)
     */
    @Override
//  @Cacheable(cacheNames = "context", key="#root.target+#root.methodName+#dock")
    public List<DockBo> getSubDocks(DockBo dock) {
        List<DockBo> docks = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Docks> dcs = this.docksRepo.findSubDocksForDock(dock.getCustomerId(), dock.getLocationId(), dock.getId());
        if( dcs != null ) {
            dcs.forEach(d ->docks.add(new DockBo().toBo(d)));
        }       
        return docks;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.csoln.service.data.ContextService#getSubDockMap(com.csoln.web.bean.DockBean)
     */
    @Override
    public Map<String, DockBo> getSubDockMap(DockBo dock) {
        Map<String, DockBo> docks = new TreeMap<>();
        List<DockBo> dcs = this.getSubDocks(dock);
        if( dcs != null ) {
            dcs.forEach(d ->docks.put(d.getAbbreviation(), d));
        }
        return docks;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.csoln.service.data.ContextService#getSubDockMapById(com.csoln.web.bean.DockBean, java.lang.String)
     */
    @Override
    public Map<Integer, DockBo> getSubDockMapById(DockBo dock) {
        Map<Integer, DockBo> docks = new TreeMap<>();
        List<DockBo> dcs = this.getSubDocks(dock);
        if( dcs != null ) {
            dcs.forEach(d ->docks.put(d.getId(), d));
        }
        return docks;
    }

    private List<String> getGrantedAuthorities(String prefix) {
        List<String> filter = new ArrayList<>();        
        Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities =  (Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority>) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities();
        Stream<SimpleGrantedAuthority> filtered = authorities.stream().filter(a -> a.getAuthority().startsWith(prefix));
        filtered.forEach(a -> filter.add(a.getAuthority().replace(prefix, "")));
        log.debug("Filtered by User:  " + filter);
        return filter;
    }

    /**
     * @return the customerPrefix
     */
    public String getCustomerPrefix() {
        return customerPrefix;
    }

    /**
     * @param customerPrefix the customerPrefix to set
     */
    public void setCustomerPrefix(String customerPrefix) {
        this.customerPrefix = customerPrefix;
    }

    /**
     * @return the locationPrefix
     */
    public String getLocationPrefix() {
        return locationPrefix;
    }

    /**
     * @param locationPrefix the locationPrefix to set
     */
    public void setLocationPrefix(String locationPrefix) {
        this.locationPrefix = locationPrefix;
    }

    /**
     * @return the dockPrefix
     */
    public String getDockPrefix() {
        return dockPrefix;
    }

    /**
     * @param dockPrefix the dockPrefix to set
     */
    public void setDockPrefix(String dockPrefix) {
        this.dockPrefix = dockPrefix;
    }
}
```

---

THE DAO

```
package com.csoln.lv.data.cld.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;

import com.csoln.lv.data.dom.Customers;
import com.csoln.data.repository.SyncRepository;

public interface CustomersRepo extends JpaRepository<Customers, Integer>, SyncRepository<Customers> {

    public List<Customers> findByAbbreviationAndActiveEntryTrue(String abbreviation);
    public List<Customers> findByIdInAndActiveEntryTrue(List<Integer> customerIds);

    @Query("SELECT new Customers(id, abbreviation, shortName, longName) FROM Customers WHERE activeEntry = true ORDER BY abbreviation ASC")
    public List<Customers> findDisplayInfo();

    @Query("SELECT new Customers(id, abbreviation, shortName, longName) FROM Customers WHERE id IN :customerIds AND activeEntry = true")
    public List<Customers> findDisplayInfoByIdIn(@Param("customerIds") List<Integer> customerIds);

    @Query("SELECT new Customers(id, abbreviation, shortName, longName) FROM Customers WHERE abbreviation IN :abbreviations AND activeEntry = true")
    public List<Customers> findDisplayInfoByAbbrIn(@Param("abbreviations") List<String> abbreviations);
}
```

---

CUSTOMERS

```
package com.csoln.lv.data.dom;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EntityListeners;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.springframework.data.domain.Persistable;

import com.csoln.data.common.AbstractAbbreviation;
import com.csoln.data.listener.SimpleSequenceId;
import com.csoln.data.listener.SimpleSequenceIdListener;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

/**
 * @author eduardo.serrano
 *
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = Customers.TABLE)
@EntityListeners(SimpleSequenceIdListener.class)
public class Customers extends AbstractAbbreviation implements Persistable<Integer>, SimpleSequenceId {

    public static final String TABLE = "customers";
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8559335312619610990L;

    @Id
    private Integer id;

    public Customers() {
        super();
    }

    public Customers(Integer id, String abbreviation, String shortName, String longName) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.setAbbreviation(abbreviation);
        this.setShortName(shortName);
        this.setLongName(longName);
    }
    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    /**
     * @param id the id to set
     */
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.data.domain.Persistable#isNew()
     */
    @Override
    @JsonIgnore
    public boolean isNew() {
        return this.id == null;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.csoln.data.common.AbstractAuditable#toString()
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new StringBuilder("\n\r\t\t" + this.getClass().getName() + " - ID: " + this.id + ", " +super.toString()).toString();
    }   
}
```

---

THE BO

```
package com.csoln.lv.cld.bo;

import com.csoln.lv.data.dom.Customers;
import com.csoln.bo.common.AuditableBo;

public class CustomerBo extends AuditableBo<CustomerBo, Customers> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6234658974110288240L;
    private Integer id;
    private String abbreviation;
    private String code;
    private String label;
    private Boolean activeEntry;

    public CustomerBo() {
        super();
    }
    public CustomerBo(Integer id, String abbreviation, String code, String label) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.abbreviation = abbreviation;
        this.code = code;
        this.label = label;
    }
    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    /**
     * @param id the id to set
     */
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    /**
     * @return the abbreviation
     */
    public String getAbbreviation() {
        return abbreviation;
    }

    public CustomerBo setAbbreviation(String abbreviation) {
        this.abbreviation = abbreviation;
        return this;
    }
    /**
     * @return the code
     */
    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public CustomerBo setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
        return this;
    }
    /**
     * @return the label
     */
    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    public CustomerBo setLabel(String label) {
        this.label = label;
        return this;
    }
    /**
     * @return the activeEntry
     */
    public Boolean getActiveEntry() {
        return activeEntry;
    }
    /**
     * @param activeEntry the activeEntry to set
     */
    public void setActiveEntry(Boolean activeEntry) {
        this.activeEntry = activeEntry;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public <B extends CustomerBo> B toBo(Customers domain) {
        if( domain != null ) {
            super.toBo(domain);

            this.id = domain.getId();
            this.abbreviation = domain.getAbbreviation();
            this.code = domain.getShortName();
            this.label = domain.getLongName();
            this.activeEntry = domain.getActiveEntry();

        } 
        return (B) this;
    }

    public Customers toDomain() {
        Customers domain = new Customers();
        domain = super.toDomain(domain);
        domain.setId(id);
        domain.setAbbreviation(abbreviation);
        domain.setLongName(this.label);
        domain.setShortName(this.code);
        domain.setActiveEntry(activeEntry);
        return domain;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        boolean equals = false;
        if( obj instanceof CustomerBo ) {
            CustomerBo i = (CustomerBo)obj;
            equals = (id == i.getId());
        }
        return equals;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return 4000;
    }
}
```

---

THE ERROR

```
 SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
    org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'contextServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'customersRepo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.csoln.lv.data.cld.dao.CustomersRepo' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.csoln.lv.data.cld.dao.CustomersRepo' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

---

THE XML SPRING CONTEXT FILE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
    <bean class="com.csoln.context.CsolnContext" /> 

    <import resource="classpath:/props-context.xml"/>

    <import resource="classpath:/config/data-context.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:/config/livedock-data-context.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:/config/security-context.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:/config/cache-context.xml" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="
        com.csoln.lookup,
        com.csoln.lv.service">
    </context:component-scan>

    <bean class="com.csoln.service.ContextServiceImpl" />
    <bean class="com.csoln.service.CodeServiceImpl" />
    <bean class="com.csoln.service.ReferenceServiceImpl" />

    <bean id="jsonProvider" class="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider" />
</beans>
```

Comment: post the Spring context file

Comment: Reimeus:  I have post the Spring Context File

Comment: Your component-scan base packages only includes com.csoln.lookup and com.csoln.lv.service however your CustomersRepo is in package com.csoln.lv.data.cld.dao.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your ComponentScan doesn't see the package where you declared your @Service. Post the Spring Context.

Comment: That is what I was reading about, but I don't know how to make the componentScan to see it, what do I need to code and where?

Comment: Do you have an applicationContext? It must be an .xml file where you declare the spring namespaces.

Comment: Oh, sorry! I've just see the xml file. Instead of this:  <context:component-scan base-package="
        com.csoln.lookup,
        com.csoln.lv.service">
    </context:component-scan> use : <context:component-scan base-package="com.csoln"/>

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `@Repository` annotation in `CustomersRepo`